# Simple Batch Script for Presto query

Tags: bash, presto

I am running a bash script to extract data from a table via presto...

```
./presto --server myprestoserver:8889 --catalog mycatalog --schema myschema --execute "select * from TABLEResultsAuditLog;" > /mydirectory/audit.dat
```

This command will successfully and extract the table results and send them to the `audit.dat` file. What I am looking for is to replace the 
`--execute "select * from TABLEResultsAuditLog;"`
section and have a file located in `/mydirectory/audit.sql` which would then contain the sql statement which I need executed. I have tried using

```
./presto --server myprestoserver:8889 --catalog mycatalog --schema myschema < /mydirectory/audit.sql > /mydirectory/audit.dat
```

where the audit.sql contains the select statement only, but this only populates the audit.dat file with the query statement and not the results. I'm not familiar with bash scripting, so its probably an easy fix for someone!!

Answer (score 6):

Presto CLI has `--file` option for this purpose:

```
presto-cli --server ... --file input.sql > output-file
```